# MYSQL (MariaDB) - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb

I have two tables called `addresses` and `house_sales`

**addresses**

```
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| house_number_name | varchar(150)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address_line1     | varchar(150)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| address_line2     | varchar(150)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address_line3     | varchar(150)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| town_city         | varchar(150)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| district          | varchar(150)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| county            | varchar(150)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| post_code         | varchar(8)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**house_sales**

```
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                                                       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11) unsigned                                           | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| address_id    | int(11) unsigned                                           | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| price         | int(11) unsigned                                           | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date          | datetime                                                   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime                                                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime                                                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to select all the addresses grouped by `address_line1` and then getting the average price for that street.  The query works but I want to only select where there is more than one house on the same street.  However when I add the `AND count(*) > 1` I get the error **"Invalid use of group function"**.  Below is the query

```
SELECT count(*) as total_sales, avg(price) as average_price, `address_line1`, `town_city`
FROM `house_sales` `hs`
LEFT JOIN `addresses` `a` ON `hs`.`address_id` = `a`.`id`
WHERE `town_city` = 'London'
AND count(*) > 1
GROUP BY `address_line1`
ORDER BY `average_price` desc
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.  I've tried a sub query so I can use `HAVING` but haven't got this to work.  Any help or pointers would be appreciated

Comment: When several tables are involved, it's good programming practice to qualify all columns, e.g. `house_sales.type`.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `having` clause to filter on the aggregate expression:

```
SELECT count(*) as total_sales, avg(price) as average_price, `address_line1`, `town_city`
FROM `house_sales` `hs`
LEFT JOIN `addresses` `a` ON `hs`.`address_id` = `a`.`id`
WHERE `town_city` = 'London'
GROUP BY `address_line1`, `town_city`
HAVING  count(*) > 1
ORDER BY `average_price` desc
```

MySQL extends the SQL standard by allowing the use of aliases in the `having` clause, so you can also do:

```
having total_sales > 1
```

Side notes:

- as commented by jarlh, it is a good practice to qualify (prefix) all column names with the table they belong to
- it is also a good practice to put all non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause (I added `town_city`, which was missing in your original query) - newer versions of MySQL do not allow this by default
- quoting all identifiers is usually not necessary (unless they contain special characters)

Comment: I knew it would be something simple, thanks for the help.  Additional points noted.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go here.  One would be to add `town_city` to the `GROUP BY` list:

```
SELECT
    address_line1,
    town_city,
    COUNT(*) AS total_sales,
    AVG(price) AS average_price
FROM house_sales hs
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON hs.address_id = a.id
WHERE town_city = 'London'
GROUP BY address_line1, town_city
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY average_price DESC;
```

The other would be to just keep your current query but remove `town_city` from the select list, since you are restricting to just London anyway.

```
SELECT
    address_line1,
    COUNT(*) AS total_sales,
    AVG(price) AS average_price
FROM house_sales hs
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON hs.address_id = a.id
WHERE town_city = 'London'
GROUP BY address_line1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY average_price DESC;
```